# How can I turn this power shell command for Active Directory into a batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

```
-groupname (Read-Host "Enter Group Name") 
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "groupname" -Recursive |
    Get-ADUser -Properties mail |
    Select-Object Name,mail |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\user\OneDrive\groupname.csv
```

When I run the command, nothing happens in PowerShell.

Comment: Why not give them the powershell?

Comment: What prevents you of putting the command into a batch-file?

Comment: I can't share the .ps1 file with the team. I would like create a batch so when they run the file, it asks for the group name and they can export the file instead of manually editing the file every time to export the list.

Comment: Seriously though. In what environment are you able to share a batch but not a powershell script? What is the logic behind that?

Comment: Also, you can ask for the groupname in a powershell script just fine.

Comment: Read inbuilt help `powershell /?`, pay your attention to `-Command` parameter.

Comment: @EBGreen I wish I could answer that question but I'm just an intern lol

Comment: @EBGreen how can I ask for the groupname in the script?

Comment: `-Identity (Read-Host "Enter Group Name")`

Comment: You would need to have access to `DSQUERY` and `DSGET` to convert that to a batch-file.  They are not installed on the domain server by default but you could ask to have them installed if you wanted to.  Regardless of that, the Powershell option should be the better choice.

Comment: You are solving the wrong problem. Find out why exactly you think you cannot use powershell and fix that.

Comment: @EBGreen I am going to use powershell. I made an error sharing the file. When I run this powershell script I'm still getting an error:

Answer (score 1):

You've used my suggestion wrong, either assign the output from `Read-Host` to a variable:

```
$groupname = Read-Host "Enter Group Name"
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname -Recursive |
    Get-ADUser -Properties mail |
    Select-Object Name,mail |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\user\OneDrive\groupname.csv
```

Or use it inline:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity (Read-Host "Enter Group Name") -Recursive |
    Get-ADUser -Properties mail |
    Select-Object Name,mail |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\user\OneDrive\groupname.csv
```

Comment: @BelairAlbahagwi Glad I could help, if you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).